# map c language into assembly language

Tags: c, assembly

I'm new to c language and want to establish the intuition to map c language into assembly language so that I can have a strong sense of how the stack, register, memory, code work when I see the c code. I have read several assembly language books, which is mainly focused on the assembly syntax rather than the relationship between c and assembly. Does anyone know where can I find such book about the map between c and assembly languages.

Comment: There is no "*the* map", different compilers do it differently, even the same compiler does it differently on different settings

Comment: C does not r3equire a stack, nor registers.

Comment: @harold  This is natural, but it doesn't seem to be relevant to this question. I definitely use a specific gcc version, and a specific option. Then observe the correspondence between c and assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if such a book exists (if it does, it'll likely be a book about compilers). However, there's an easier solution: try it.

Write some C code, then compile it with debug symbols (these instructions assume linux):

```
gcc foo.c -o foo
```

Then, use a debugger:

```
gdb ./foo
break MyFunction
run
disass
```

This will set a breakpoint on `MyFunction`, then run the program until it reaches that breakpoint. `disass` will print the assembly for that function. You can use `stepi` to step one instruction at a time, or `next` to step one C line at a time.

Comment: Alternatively, run `gcc -S foo.c` to have the compiler produce the assembly file directly (this may leave a little bit more information about the mapping in the assembly file).